# Node-gyp issue with, cannot find module

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I installed node-gyp as a global module `npm install node-gyp -g`
When I run `node-gyp`, the bellow issue occurred

current node version 'v15.0.1'
Os Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Looking for some help.

```
node-gyp
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:903
  throw err;
  ^
```

```
Error: Cannot find module 'nopt'

Require stack:
 /usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js
 /usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:900:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:745:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have the same error, did you found a solution?

Comment: I had this issue and resolved downgrading node to v12. I don't know if it is the same problem for you, but something in my project is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

What helped in my case is running it with `su` permissions:
`sudo node-gyp configure`